# Combining multiple armatures

Tags: animation, armature

I recently started animating a character wearing armor and I decided the best way to handle the deformations of the various armor pieces would be to create separate armatures for them, for several reasons. However, I had to realize that it's not possible to export something like that into Unity or Unreal, since they don't allow for multiple roots. So I wanted to combine the armatures. Now, the problem I am facing is that the animations are already done, and whenever I join the armatures, they get moved around in a different position than they originally were, and when I play the animations, the positions and rotations of the armor armature bones are completely off. Is there a way to join/parent the armatures without everything getting messed up? Or do I have to start anew?

Here are the things I tried:
1. Joining the armatures with CTRL+J
2. Parenting one armature to the other (to a bone, and to object)
3. Using the child of constraint

Thanks for any input!